# MySQL - Running hourly average of the difference between datasets

Tags: mysql, average

**The setup**
I have a table below called votes. I have a script that runs every minute and gathers data on 20 items. The script saves the id of the item, the total running vote count for the item, and the datetime the entry was added.

**The question**
What I want to do is calculate the Month-To-Date average votes per hour. Keeping in mind the votes field contains the running total votes for the item so for instance votes per hour would be calculated by taking the difference from an entry taken on 2013-03-01 00:01:01 minus an entry from 2013-03-01 00:00:01. I need to calculate that delta for each hour and each of the 20 items then take the average of those results for each individual item. The result set be 20 values, the average votes per hour from March 1st to the current date for each of the 20 items.

I have something working in code loops but I would like to get this into a single MySQL statement. So far all my attempts are not yielding anything close to the desired result set.

**The table (the first two script iterations)**

> |//**id**//|int(11)
>  |item_id|int(11)
>  |votes|int(11)
>   |date_added|datetime
>  |id|item_id|votes|date_added|
>   |1|1|1|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>  |2|2|1|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>   |3|3|0|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>  |4|4|0|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>   |5|5|0|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>  |6|6|0|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>   |7|7|0|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>  |8|8|0|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>   |9|9|0|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>  |10|10|0|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>   |11|11|0|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>  |12|12|0|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>   |13|13|0|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>  |14|14|0|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>   |15|15|0|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>  |16|16|0|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>   |17|17|0|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>  |18|18|0|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>   |19|19|0|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>  |20|20|0|2013-03-01 00:00:01
>   --
>  |21|1|10|2013-03-01 00:01:01
>  |22|2|13|2013-03-01 00:01:01
>  |23|3|5|2013-03-01 00:01:01
>  |24|4|6|2013-03-01
>   00:01:01
>  |25|5|1|2013-03-01 00:01:01
>  |26|6|8|2013-03-01
>   00:01:01
>  |27|7|9|2013-03-01 00:01:01
>  |28|8|3|2013-03-01
>   00:01:01
>  |29|9|10|2013-03-01 00:01:01
>  |30|10|2|2013-03-01
>   00:01:01
>  |31|11|2|013-03-01 00:01:01
>  |32|12|9|2013-03-01
>   00:01:01
>  |33|13|3|2013-03-01 00:01:01
>  |34|14|5|2013-03-01
>   00:01:01
>  |35|15|9|2013-03-01 00:01:01
>  |36|16|1|2013-03-01
>   00:01:01
>  |37|17|2|2013-03-01 00:01:01
>  |38|18|1|2013-03-01
>   00:01:01
>  |39|19|6|2013-03-01 00:01:01
>  |40|20|3|2013-03-01
>   00:01:01

Comment: I guess this was as difficult as I thought...

Comment: Am I incorrect in assuming that this could be done in a MySQL statement at all?